Как применить материал к камере | Unity
У меня есть камера, а также кастомный URP шейдер, применённый на материал. Вопрос: как применить этот материал к камере, что картинка, которую выводит камера, изменилась? Я новичок в Юнити, особенно в PP и шейдерах. Мне нужно просто применить парочку таких материалов на камеру. Есть какие-нибудь простые способы с Post-Processing и без? Версия Юнити 2021 года
